# UISplitViewController detecting Back Button pressed

Tags: swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController where I want to always display the master and detail view controllers for iPads. This line takes care of that for me:

```
// Always display master and detail in large screens
self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

In the prepareForSegue, when opening up the detail view controllers, I have the following lines of code for the Back Button

```
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Now when the user pressed that back button, I will want to perform an action after the Master view controller is hidden. I am not having any luck finding how to do that. In the SplitViewControllerDelegate I attempted to use:

```
func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeToDisplayMode displayMode: UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)
```

But that function is called before the Detail view controller becomes full screen. Is there a function or something else I can do to help notify me when the UISplitViewController finishes hiding the Master View?

Comment: What about putting it in `viewDidDisappear` for the master view controller?

Comment: I put println statements in viewDidDisappear, viewWillDisappear, viewWillAppear and they aren't called when I show and hide the master view controller.

Comment: @MikeWalker did you have any lucky ?

Comment: @Steve I have not had any luck with this unfortunately.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observer on the view's with in the DetailViewController, and perform your specific action when it triggers:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"view.frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  if ([self observationInfo]) {
    @try {
      [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"view.frame"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {}

  }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  if (object == self && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"view.frame"]) {
    // do your action here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `delegate` method

```
- (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218416/4833705). You need to **put it in** the **MasterController** (the one on the left side).

FYI this inactivated the expand button and to get it to expand/retract I put the extra code inside `doSomethingWhenExpandButtonTapped()`

```
navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.action = #selector(doSomethingWhenExpandButtonTapped)
navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.target = self

@objc func doSomethingWhenExpandButtonTapped() {
    print("splitViewController's expand and back button pressed")

    if splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode == .allVisible {
        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    } else {
        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }
}
```