# Swift iOS- Trigger action when SplitViewController's displayModeButtonItem is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I have a SplitViewController and I'm implementing:

```
myNavVC?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
myNavVC?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

I use it to display the expand button on the view controller when the iPhone 6 Plus or 7 Plus is in `.regular` orientation. I would like to trigger an action when the button is touched. How I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set [action](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617127-action) on button.

```
myNavVC?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.action = #selector(foo)
```

Also you need to set the target, the object with receive the action. Probably it would be `self` in your case.

```
myNavVC?.topViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target = self
```

Comment: thanks I'm going to try it later and get back to you! :)

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. crash > "unrecognized instance sent to selector"

Comment: You need to set a [target](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617154-target)